# Clear Submission on google form confirmation page

Tags: google-forms

I have many google forms that are used dozens of times daily. I regularly am running into issues where users are keeping a form confirmation page open and it re sending the data days later. Is there anyway to clear the submission data on a google form confirmation page to prevent this from happening?

I know I cannot redirect users. I have changed the confirmation page to remind them to close it out, but I'm dealing with a lot of firefighters who do not like to listen.